# How to create self referential relationship in laravel?

Tags: laravel-4

I am new to Laravel. I Just want to create a self referential model. For example, I want to create a product category in which the field `parent_id` as same as product category id. How is this possible?

Model Shown below

```
class Product_category extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        'parent_id' => 'required'
    );

     function product_category()
    {
        return $this->belongsto('Product_category','parent_id');
    }
}
```

It results Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! Error

Comment: Why? Why do you want to retrieve the exact same instance as a relationship?

Comment: Hi Cryode, My intention is to create a model Category in which its parent is one of the previous category in the same model.That is category model have different sub categories. Some category element have parent category which was one of the previous entries in category model.

Comment: For Laravel to work properly, your class name should be `ProductCategory`, not `Product_category`.

Comment: @Cryode It's called a tree.

Comment: I have my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70563109/8360374), maybe you can take a look the example.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can add a relation to the model and set the custom key for the relation field.

**Update:**

Try this construction

```php
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

**Old answer:**

```php
class Post extends Eloquent {

    function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('Post', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hai JacKPoint,
              It results an error "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!" .

Comment: How to access those elements. Is it possible through $Post->parent->name?

Comment: @Praveen See my answer for accessing the parents!

Comment: I think you should be able to do something like

`public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post', 'id', 'parent_id');
    }`
The id is the parent id and you can map it other columns referencing model is as parent_id

Answer (score 13):

Your model is not at fault for producing the "maximum function nesting level of '100' reached" error. It's XDebug's configuration; increase your `xdebug.max_nesting_level`.

The following is from [a 2015 post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-aborting/replies/62431) by @sitesense on laracasts.com:

> This is not a bug in Laravel, Symfony or anything else. It only occurs when XDebug is installed.
>
> It happens simply because 100 or more functions are called recursively. This is not a high figure as such and later versions of XDebug (>= 2.3.0) have raised this limit to 256. See here:
>
> http://bugs.xdebug.org/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=00001100
>
> EDIT: In fact the latest Homestead provisioning script already sets the limit to 250. See line 122 here:
>
> https://github.com/laravel/settler/blob/master/scripts/provision.sh#L122

So the addition of `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250` to `php.ini` should do it.

Comment: this one actually should have helped to solve OPs issue. i dont understand y would someone down vote this +1.. :)

Answer (score 5):

I've added a little more to the code based on your comments trying to access the parent!

```php
class Person extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];
    var $mom, $kids;

    function __construct() { 
        if($this->dependency_id<>0) {
            $this->mother->with('mother');  
        }
    }

    public function children() {
        $children = $this->hasMany('Person','dependency_id');
        foreach($children as $child) {
            $child->mom = $this;
        }
        return  $children;
    }

    public function mother() {
        $mother = $this->belongsTo('Person','dependency_id');
        if(isset($mother->kids)) {
            $mother->kids->merge($mother);
        }
        return $mother;
    }
}
```

Then you can access the parent from the child with eager loading, see more here: http://neonos.net/laravel-eloquent-model-parentchild-relationship-with-itself/

Answer (score -1):

you can refer self, using $this

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany($this, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70563109/8360374).
The key is this code below in Model.php

```
public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Structure::class, 'parent_id')->with('children');
    }
```