# Laravel self related model

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Since I designed my db, I came out with a self related model in my entity relational diagram. I have the entity country and the relation that go from country to the same country that is called passyingby and it has its own attributes transfer description.
So I would have tables:
country(nameCountry), passyingby(nameCountry1,nameCountry2,transfer_description).
How can I manage this in Laravel considering also the unique values of passyingby rows? I have created a migration to create the table country and its related model.

Comment: And all that with zero lines of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create self referential relationship in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923773/how-to-create-self-referential-relationship-in-laravel)