# Is it possible to relate the same table using "hasMany" in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I kinda stuck here while creating a chat system using Laravel I have created the table to store message like this

```
inbox_message
->id (PK)
->message
->sentTo
->belongsTo
->isStarred
->isRead
->isDraft
->group_message_id (FK) in the same table (inbox_messages).
```

Now, group_message_id will work as FK with reference to ID (both FK and PK are in same table)

For fetching I've implemented `hasMany` relationship like this

```
public function child(){
    return $this->hasMany(message::class,'group_message_id','id');
}
```

Now, instead of getting all the message within child I'm getting `[]` array in child and getting all messages separately like this.

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "message": "msg2 by patient6 to doctor 3",
        "belongsTo": 6,
        "sentTo": 3,
        "isStarred": 0,
        "isDraft": 0,
        "isRead": 1,
        "group_message_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2017-09-05 03:48:19",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-05 06:52:33",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "child": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "message": "msg4 by patient6 to doctor 3",
        "belongsTo": 6,
        "sentTo": 3,
        "isStarred": 0,
        "isDraft": 0,
        "isRead": 1,
        "group_message_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2017-09-05 03:54:35",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-05 06:52:33",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "child": []
    }
]
```

The query I did to fetch the results

```
$userMsgs = message::with( [
                    'child' => function ( $query ) {
                        $query->where( 'isDraft', '!=', 1 );
                    }
                ] )->where( 'isDraft', '!=', 1 )
                                   ->where( 'sentTo', $authId )
                                   ->get();
```

Question is it possible to relate same table in eloquent if yes then please let me know where I'm wrong?

Thanks for the help I'm in much need :)

Comment: anyone here for help???

Comment: you might need to implement Self Referential Relation. Check :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923773/how-to-create-self-referential-relationship-in-laravel

Comment: looks like helpful but now how should I call in my controller what will be the query here?

Comment: can you please show the Query , so that i can help.

Comment: yeah check the question

Comment: i mean to say controller code

Comment: yes I have added the code I mean the query which I have used to fetch

Comment: it will work , are you getting wrong output?

Comment: hey thanks I'm getting the right output currently please post it as an answer so that I can approve however, I will test it through hope that you will be there if I stuck somewhere thanks again :)

Comment: my office hour is about to complete. so can help if needed tomorrow.

Comment: hey there is a problem here I found it it is not working when my logged id is in sentTo working well If it is in belongsTo

Comment: because you have condition for `where( 'sentTo', $authId )` not for `belongsTo`

Comment: ok please post it as answer so i can upvote and will test it further thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153732/discussion-between-meera-tank-and-bhavik-bamania).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using Self Relation

```
class message extends Eloquent {

   function child(){
       return $this->hasMany('message', 'group_message_id');
   }
}
```

Hope This will Help.

Comment: hey, it is working fine with the inbox but if I am trying to fetch sent items I'm getting wrong response getting all msgs separately however I'm getting all those messages in child array too..

Comment: Do you have any flag for sent item?? then just filter it.

Comment: no I'm just checking it using authid in belongsTo field

Comment: which key you had set to identify that msg is sent by me | authid?? if belongsTo is that field it should work

Comment: if your logged user id is in belongsTo then it is sent by you and if logged user Id is in sentTo then you got that message in your inbox

Comment: using Auth I can fetch logged user Id

Comment: check your DB do you have any record where belongsTo  is not equal your userid?

Comment: yes I have some conversation that were not initialised by me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153736/discussion-between-meera-tank-and-bhavik-bamania).