# creating self referencing entities in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

i have a situation where i have entity, base, which can contain ingredients, drinks and bases itself. I know how to make relations to ingredients and drinks, but do not know how to do it when it comes to bases within base. Any help would be appreciated. I can not use solution with parent_id, because one base can belong to several other bases, and do not want duplicates in the bases table. I need some solution with pivot table.

Comment: like a base have children bases and  a parent base ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you trying to achieve here. show us examples or some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create self referential relationship in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923773/how-to-create-self-referential-relationship-in-laravel)

Comment: i want to build a form for base, and in that form i will have select box for ingredient and drink, but i need one more, base. so base can have lets say salt, water, and some other base, like sauce which is actually a base entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found  solution, self referencing entity can be done with itself with Many To Many relation.

Model relation look like this :

```
class BaseDrink extends Model {

  public function drinkbase(){

     return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\BaseDrink', 'basedrink_basedrink','basedrink_id', 'parent_basedrink_id')
        ->withPivot('created_by')
        ->withPivot('last_modified_by')
        ->withPivot('id')
        ->withTimestamps();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `parent_id` in `bases` table

```
class Base extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Base::class,'parent_id','id');
    }

    public function parent()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Base::class,'id','parent_id');
    }
}
```

And then you can easily access bases of a base like this

```
foreach($base->children() as $childBase){

   $childBase->ingredients();
   $childBase->drinks();
}
```

Comment: i do not have parent_id, i was thinking of making pivot table. Because one base can have many other bases.

Comment: @VeljkoSirovljević By the way why don't you try the above solution ?   You saeid  "Because one base can have many other bases" Is not it the hasMany relation which I have provide ?

Comment: because when i list bases, there will be same several records with different parent_id, and i don't want this to be the case.

Comment: So what's the problem ? you said a base can have bases, so its their parent

Comment: the problem is that by having parent_id in the bases table, there will be records which are same, only difference will be parent_id, and this is not desired behavior. I must use pivot table...

Comment: are you sure belongsto takes local id foreign id? The documentation says to use foreign key as first parameter and then the local id as the second...