# laravel eager loading for self relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-5.8

I have the model that has relation to itself like this

```
public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany(AppointmentPart::class,'parent_id');
}
```

I want to eager loading for queries for this model but because every row can have child *with()* method doesn't work for me

```
$parts = AppointmentPart::whereParentId(0)->with('children')->get();
```

my blade:

```
<ul id="treeData">
                     @foreach($parts as $part)
                          <li id="{{ $part->id }}"
                                        @if(!empty($part->children)) class="folder" @endif>
                                        {{ $part->title }}
                                        @if(!empty($part->children))
                                            @include('appointment::admin.appointment.layout._part_child', array('parts' => $part->children))
                                        @endif
                      </li>
                  @endforeach
</ul>
```

content of _part_child :

```
<ul>
    @foreach($parts as $part)
        <li id="{{ $part->id }}" @if(!empty($part->children)) class="folder" @endif>
            {{ $part->title }}
            @include('appointment::admin.appointment.layout._part_child',['parts'=>$part->children])
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

how can I do this?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve... Can you add also the code where you use the `with()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `whereHas()` function. Have a look at the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

> If you need even more power, you may use the whereHas and orWhereHas methods to put "where" conditions on your has queries. These methods allow you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint [...]

So in your case you have to change your method as follows:

```
$parts = AppointmentPart::with('children')->whereHas('children', function($query) use ($parent_id) {
    $query->where('parent_id', '=', $parent_id);
})->get();
```

you can also create a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#local-scopes) in order to create a reusable query statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for you. This might help to solve your problem. I have Structure Model which contain organizational structure of a company.

In my StructureController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        $parentStructures = Structure::where('parent_id', 0)->get();
        return view('structure.structureTreeview', compact('parentStructures'));
    }
```

In my Structure.php, I add *with()* at the relationship for eager loading.

```
public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Structure::class, 'parent_id')->with('children');
    }
```

And, if you you check with this package [here](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-query-detector) , it won't show any warning.

Reference : check this website [here](https://www.codecheef.org/article/hierarchical-treeview-category-example-in-laravel)