# How to use laravel eloquent relationships when you want to join a table with other table twice by using aliases

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have two tables trip and trip_stops

**trip table structure:**

```
id - int,pk
departure_date
arrival_date
created_at
updated_at
```

**trip_stops structure**

```
id - int, pk
trip_id - fk
stop_name
sequence_number
```

now I want to join these two tables on basis of input provided by user, I have done it by using raw SQL query but i wanted to know if this can be done by using laravel eloquent relationship.

Raw SQL:

```
select * from trips inner join trip_stops departure_city on trips.id = departure_city.trip_id inner join trip_stops arrival_cities on trips.id=arrival_cities.trip_id where departure_city.stop_name='Dehradun' and arrival_cities.stop_name='Delhi' and departure_city.sequence_number < arrival_cities.sequence_number
```

Comment: Does it have to be a `join` ? could you not have 2 relationships instead?

Comment: yes we can call 2 relationships as well, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Trip::join('trip_stops as departure_city', 'departure_city.trip_id', '=', 'trips.id')
    ->join('trip_stops as arrival_cities', 'arrival_cities.trip_id', '=', 'trips.id')
    ->where('departure_city.stop_name', 'Dehradun')
    ->where('arrival_cities.stop_name', 'Delhi')
    ->whereRaw('departure_city.sequence_number', '<', 'arrival_cities.sequence_number');
```

Alternately use DB instead,

```
 DB::table('trips')
```

**Edit: We have to use whereRaw instead of where while comparing the sequence number because using where will take the other parameter as a value**

Comment: Thanks, it works fine just a small change needed, We have to use whereRaw instead of where while comparing the sequence number because using where will take the other parameter as a value. ```whereRaw('departure_city.sequence_number', '<', 'arrival_cities.sequence_number')```

Comment: Oh sorry missed that, glad you found out

Comment: yes! Is there a way to do it using eloquent  relationships only?

Comment: You can try `return $this->belongsTo('Parent', 'parent_id');`
I don't think it is good option as it might make things getting complicated if you do so, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923773/how-to-create-self-referential-relationship-in-laravel/31824108

Comment: I have already created the relationship between the model but I just can't figure out how to do this aliasing part, like we are giving 2 aliases to the trip_stops table, how to do this using eloquent?

Comment: Oh a little confused, I don't think your condition can be solved with only `relationship`, for instance: `Trip::join('trip_stops as departure_city', 'departure_city.trip_id', '=', 'trips.id')` is a relationship, `->join('trip_stops as arrival_cities', 'arrival_cities.trip_id', '=', 'trips.id')` is another relationship, when you get the two relationship, you have to compare both relationship result, which makes thing complicated.

Comment: When you define relationship, example, `return $this->belongsTo('trip_stops', 'trip_id');`, it will generate the SQL `SELECT * from trip_stops where id = $1`, which is not what you want (the join query), you can install Laravel debugbar to checkout the sql.